# Why my map reduce job is running sequentially?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a 4 node cluster and a total of 96GB of memory.

I have divided my inputs to 100 files and set the job to have 100 Mappers. While from the log it seems that the Mappers are running sequentially.

```
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: Total input paths to process : 100
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: number of splits:100
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: Starting task: attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1244628585_0001
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: Processing split: hdfs://.../input/in10:0+2
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Task:attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Task attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Saved output of task 'attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0' to hdfs://.../output/_temporary/0/task_local1244628585_0001_m_000000
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: hdfs://.../input/in10:0+2
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Task 'attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0' done.
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Finishing task: attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000000_0
[2014/10/08 15:22:38] INFO: Starting task: attempt_local1244628585_0001_m_000001_0
```

....

And on and on.
Basically, It finishes one task before starting another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in local mode:

```
[2014/10/08 15:22:36] INFO: Starting task: attempt_**local**1244628585_0001_m_000000_0
```

Depending on your Hadoop version you either need to configure the JobTracker address, or the ResourceManager address.